# Cantor-like Set not of measure zero

Tags: lebesgue-measure, real-numbers, cantor-set

I have a short question, but that keeps me stuck for a couple of days.

Let's start saying that Cantor Set is defined as:

$$C:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{\alpha_n}{3^n}, \alpha_n\in\{0,2\}\right\}$$

So my question: how to modify this construction of the Cantor set in order to obtain another set “full of holes” but not of measure zero?
Also the new construction has to be made restricting, in some way (and here there is the problem), q-ary expression of real numbers in $[0,1]$.

Any idea?
Thank you.

PS:
I searched for existing questions on the subject, but I found only constructions that use infinite intersections between sets.

Comment: Kenny's comment is spot on, but the link doesn't work. Here's a working link for the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Volterra–Cantor_set)

Comment: I'm searching a construction made by restricting q-ary expression of real numbers in [0,1] (as in the original Cantor Set), not by infinite intersections of sets (as in the link).

Answer (score 1):

Something like $\{\sum\limits_n \frac{\alpha_n}{2^{2^n}} | 0 < \alpha_n < 2^{2^{n - 1}}\}$. This mean for every $k$ we require having at least one non-zero digit in positions $2^k, \ldots 2^{k + 1} - 1$.

Each such restriction multiplies measure of our set by $\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{k + 1}}\right)$. As  $\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{k}}\right) > 0$, our set has positive measure.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand: your expansion is not a q-ary expression of a real number. It may be a binary expansion at first sight (so, q=2), but if this were the case, $\alpha_n$ could be only 0 or 1, and not assume all those values.
In the original definition of Cantor Set, for example, it was defined using a ternary expansion with some restrictions.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is restriction to the first digit in binary after dot, then to the second and the third (requiring that at least one of 2nd and 3rd is $1$), then to 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th (again, requiring at least one of them is $1$), and so on.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm making a lot of effort to visually imagine this set. Have you an image, an animation or something similar?

Comment: I have to remove these numbers (binary representation):
0.00xxxxxx....
0.x00xxxxx....
0.xxx0000x....

Comment: I don't have an image. It's actually quite similar to any Cantor set: on each step you remove some "central" part of each segment. After the first two iterations we get $[\frac{5}{8}; 1)$. Starting from this on $n$-th iteration from each segment we remove central part with length of $2^{2^n}$.